# Google Stackdriver Log Based Metrics: how to extract values using a regular expression from the log line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have log lines of the following form in my Google Cloud Console:

> Updated blacklist info about 123 minions. max_blacklist_per_minion=20, median_blacklist_per_minion=8, blacklist_free_minions=31

And I'm trying to set up some log-based metrics to get a longer-term overview of the values (ie. how are they changing? is it lower or higher than yesterday? etc).

However I didn't find any examples for this scenario in the documentation and what I could think of doesn't seem to work. Specifically I'm trying to understand what I need to select in "Field name" to have access to the log line (so that I can write a regular expression against).

I tried `textPayload` but that seems to be empty for this log entry. Looking at the actual log entry there should also be a `protoPayload.line[0]`, but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: did you get any solution for your query?

Comment: @PrakashSingh - unfortunately, no. I also posted it to Google Groups - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/DB4aZG0Wg8k - hopefully somebody there can help with the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Metric Editor" built into the logs viewer UI you can use "protoPayload.line.logMessage" as the field name. For some reason the UI doesn't want to suggest 'line' (seems like a bug; same behavior in the filter box).

The log based metric won't distinguish based on the index of the app log line, so something like 'line[0]' won't work. For a distribution all values are extracted. A count metric would count the log entry (ie 1 regardless the number of 'line' matches).